# How do I remove newline symbols inside emacs vertical border

Tags: emacs, word-wrap, long-lines

I love `adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode`, which makes a soft-wrap whenever you overcome your window width, nicely formatting text in next line with a non-real ("soft") indentation.

But there is one problem with it. Whenever this happens -- emacs draws a "newline" symbol on both sides of it's vertical line, and those symbols do take my attention to those lines, defeating the whole purpose of adaptive-wrap (to not break visual indentation of code with long lines).

Question is: how do I remove those symbols on left and right?

[image]

Comment: Found a solution for text-based emacs: `(set-display-table-slot standard-display-table 'wrap ?\ )`, but can't figure out how to do the same for GUI one.

Comment: Here are my settings:  `(setq fringe-indicator-alist '( (truncation left-arrow right-arrow) (continuation nil nil) (overlay-arrow . right-triangle) (up . up-arrow) (down . down-arrow) (top top-left-angle top-right-angle) (bottom bottom-left-angle bottom-right-angle top-right-angle top-left-angle) (top-bottom left-bracket right-bracket top-right-angle top-left-angle) (empty-line . empty-line) (unknown . question-mark)))`  The answer by `phils` below is similar in that the continuation is being set to left and right as `nil`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```el
(setf (cdr (assq 'continuation fringe-indicator-alist))
      '(nil nil) ;; no continuation indicators
      ;; '(nil right-curly-arrow) ;; right indicator only
      ;; '(left-curly-arrow nil) ;; left indicator only
      ;; '(left-curly-arrow right-curly-arrow) ;; default
      )
```

I suggest trying "right indicator only", as I suspect it's only the left side which is drawing your attention, and this way you will still have the information available.

Comment: Perfect! Will try that out, thanks. You're correct that only left one is distracting, will see.

Comment: weird, didn't work for me at all https://i.imgur.com/wIPemaP.png . Emacs 24.4.1 on OS X installed via brew.

Comment: Ok, if I run `visual-line-mode` to disable that -- it'll work.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest solution: just don't show the fringe. Put this in your init file:

```
(fringe-mode '(0 . 0))
```